# `ls -l` for all parent directories

Tags: linux, bash, ls

I want to get a list of all directory permissions from current folder to `/`. For example, for the directory: `/var/lib/program/subfolder`, I want an output such as:

```sh
$ pwd
/var/lib/program/subfolder
$ magic_ls_-l_command somefile
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 May 15 20:20 var
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 May 15 20:20 lib
drwxrwxr-x 10 root user 4096 May 16 20:21 program
drwxrwxr-x 10 root user 4096 May 16 20:21 subfolder
-rwxrwxr--  1 root user 4096 May 16 20:22 somefile
```

I don't care about the order (from `/var` to `/subfolder` or the other way around), the number of hard links or even the date. I just wrote them down to emulate the `ls -l` output. Also, I don't care how each filename in printed (`/var` and `/lib`, `var` and `lib`, or `/var` and `/var/lib`). I'm just interested in the ownership of each file/directory in the path from the choosen file or `pwd` to `/`.

In case I should install some program, I'm under Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Unless you clarify what is the expected behavior when one of the path components in `somefile`'s path is a symlink, it's nearly impossible to post a correct answer to this question.

Comment: @oguzismail In case of symlinks, I want to see the permissions of the pointed-to file or directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question has already been answered in [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/685576/how-can-i-list-permissions-of-every-component-in-a-file-path) (I don't know if I can mark a question from one site as duplicate from another). The solution is as simple as writing (assuming I am in the same directory as the target filename):

```
$ namei -l $(pwd)/somefile   ## or `namei -l $(realpath -s somefile)`
```

Because of `-l`, it lists basic permissions in long format for each parent directory.

I have to use `pwd`/`realpath`  because `namei` doesn't resolve relative paths. If I'm not in the target directory, just write the full path.

Comment: Wow, never heard of it until today

Comment: @oguzismail Yeah there's lots of uncommon commands that are actually very useful, like `pstree`.

Comment: You can replace `$(pwd)/somefile` by `$(realpath -s somefile)`. WIth the `-s` it will not follow the symlink.

Comment: @BobaFit The `namei` option `-n` won't follow symlinks either.

Comment: That's not the only reason I'm thinking of choosing `realpath` with that you can resolve the whole path, even if it's not in your working direcotry.

Comment: Also never heard of `namei`, really cool. The problem with using `realpath -s` though is that it won't resolve a symlink if it's the file/directory you invoked it at, but it will still follow the parent directories' symlinks. So if for example you're at `/home/leo/test/`, and `/home/leo` is a symlink to `/mnt/leo`, `realpath -s .` will give you `/mnt/leo/test` instead of `/home/leo/test`.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a bash script for you. It'll have some bugs, if you have space in names. If it bothers you, I'm happy for changes recommendations in the comments.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -z "$1" ] && [ -e "$1" ]
then
 path=`realpath -s "$1"` # read argument as absolute path
else
 path="$PWD" # No valid argument, so we take pwd
fi
paths=""
while [ "$path" != / ];do
 paths+=" $path" 
 path=`dirname "$path"`
done
paths+=" $path" # Adding / to pathlist too 
ls -ld $paths
```

With `realpath -s` you can catch the absolute path, but you wont follow the link. If no argument is given, we will use pwd as the file/directory to list.

We append each path to a list. This gives us the advantage of a better layout in the end, so that we get a nice table because we run `ls` only once.

Output:

```
bobafit:~$ magic_ls_-l_command /usr/bin/python3
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root   4096 Jun 20 10:07 /
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root   4096 Sep  5  2019 /usr
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 110592 Jun 20 10:07 /usr/bin
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      9 Apr  7 12:43 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8
```

Answer (score 5):

I made this small script that does this. I use `cd "$1"; pwd` to get the current directory so that paths are not canonicalized (say, if you try `magic-ls .` and your current directory is /var/lib/postgres, but that is a symlink to /mnt/postgres, you will get `/var`, `/var/lib` and `/var/lib/postgres`, while using `realpath` you would get `/mnt` and `/mnt/postgres`)

```
magic-ls() {
    local current=$(cd "$1"; pwd)

    while [[ $current != '/' ]]; do
        ls -ld "$current"
        current=$(dirname "$current")
    done
}
```

Here's an example output:

```
[leodag@desk ~]$ magic-ls
drwx------ 1 leodag leodag 2722 jun 21 13:49 /home/leodag
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18 mai  2  2019 /home
```

By the way it will also work with no argument since `cd ""` does not change your directory.

Edit: removed `realpath` from the while check, since that could lead to unexpected results if there was a link to `/` in the path, and was unneeded.

Comment: Yes, it will fail if $1 is not a directory, I didn't cover that situation. `ls -ld` does print symbolic links here, however. Keep in mind it will be called with the absolute path to the symbolic link, maybe you tested in another way?

Comment: My bad, that's right. `realpath` will dereference symbolic links though, and whether OP wants that or not is not clear at all.

Comment: Yes, that is true, if there is a link to `/` in the path, it may cause unexpected results. I'll change that.

Comment: you can use `realpath -s` that keeps the path of the symbolic link.

Comment: I didn't know about `realpath -s`, thanks! In this case it's essentially equivalent to the variable itself, sice I just need to check for `/`, so I'll leave at that

Answer (score 3):

Just using parameter expansion:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
path="$1"
while test -n "$path"; do
    ls -lLd "$path"
    path="${path%/*}"
done
```

calling method :

```
bash test.sh /var/lib/program/subfolder/somefile
```

giving

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 21 18:49 /var/lib/program/subfolder/somefile
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jun 21 18:49 /var/lib/program/subfolder
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jun 21 18:49 /var/lib/program
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jun 21 18:49 /var/lib
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jun 13 19:24 /var
```

Answer (score 1):

This should possibly work:

```
pwd ; ls -lh ; while true ; do  cd .. ; pwd ; ls -lh ; [[ "$PWD" == "/" ]] && break ; done
```

EDIT: I misunderstood the question at first. Try this:

```
(pwd ; ls -ldh ; while true ; do cd .. ; pwd ; ls -ldh ; [[ "$PWD" == "/" ]] &&
break ; done ; cd "$START")
```

EDIT2: fillipe's answer is probably the best, but here's my third and last attempt, which works on both files and directories:

```
magic_ls() {
fname="$1"
while true ; do
ls -lhd "$fname"
[[ "$fname" == "/" ]] && break ;
fname=$(dirname $(readlink -f "$fname"))
done
}
```

Comment: First I thougth of something likte that too. The problem here is that in the end, you are not in your direcorty anymore and you get the whole files inside of that folder too. Do you know the `-d` option for `ls`? I learned it for this specific question.

Comment: Boba Fit, ah, I didn't notice that it was printing directories recursively. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question at first. You just want the permissions of each component in a specified path. I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /bin/bash

cur=""
IFS="/"
path=`pwd`

for dir in ${path:1}
do
        cur=$cur/$dir
        ls -lhd "$cur"
done

cur=$cur/$1
ls -lhd "$cur"
```

Terminal Session:

```
$ pwd 
/tmp/dir_underscore/dir space/dir special @!)
$ ls 
bash.sh  test.txt
$ ./bash.sh test.txt
drwxrwxrwt 28 root root 36K Jun 21 22:45 /tmp
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jun 21 22:27 /tmp/dir_underscore
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jun 21 22:28 '/tmp/dir_underscore/dir space'
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jun 21 22:54 '/tmp/dir_underscore/dir space/dir special @!)'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 21 22:29 '/tmp/dir_underscore/dir space/dir special @!)/test.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents. My mac doesn't have the namei command (perhaps homebrew has a copy), but wanted to whip up a quick version that aligned the output in top-down order

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
path="${1%/}"
DIRS=()
while test -n "$path"; do
  DIRS=( "$path" "${DIRS[@]}" )
  path="${path%/*}"
done
ls -ld "${DIRS[@]}"
```

Example output:

```
$ lspath $TMPDIR
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root  wheel    11 Oct  5  2018 /var -> private/var
drwxr-xr-x    7 root  wheel   224 Jul 16  2020 /var/folders
drwxr-xr-x@   3 root  wheel    96 Apr  5  2018 /var/folders/0c
drwxr-xr-x@   5 me    staff   160 Apr  5  2018 /var/folders/0c/2_s_qxd11m3d1smzqdrs3qg40000gp
drwx------@ 255 me    staff  8160 Oct  7 09:18 /var/folders/0c/2_s_qxd11m3d1smzqdrs3qg40000gp/T
```